# MVC Allow anonymous, still get current user when logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem with my MVC 4.0/Razor site.

It's a (not yet launched) public site that I recently inherited. 
90% of all pages should be available to everyone, the rest are for superusers and need authentication.

This is handled via an AllowAnonymous attribute on the public facing pages, implemented like this;

```
public class RequireAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) ||
                                filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(
                                    typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);
        if (!skipAuthorization)
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that I want a few customizations of the public facing sites (for the sake of argument, let's assume a "Currently logged in: XYZ"-label somewhere). What I've tried is using the User.Identity, but on all pages with AllowAnonymous, User.Identity.Name == "", even though a super user did log in. (And if he changes the url to a page *with* authentication, he's logged in again, and User.Identity.Name is correct).

Is there any way to both use Allow Anonymous and keep track of who's logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved this.

The problem was our custom subdomain routing. I had to override the "domain" setting so it points to `.example.com` instead of `example.com` for the cookies (mainly aspxauth).

The reason this took some time to realize was a number of other custom made parts, potentially interfering in the application, especially:

- Custom membership provider
- Custom AllowAnonymous attribute (even when there's a standard attribute now)
- And the fact that I thought this was the normal behavior when in fact it's not.

Summary: 
If implementing a subdomain routing rule AND need authentication that follows along the subdomains, you must change the base domain of the cookies.